# undefined after adding excel libs to meteor

Tags: javascript, excel, mongodb, meteor

I want to export data on my web page to Excel file. After some digging I've found [meteor-excel](https://atmospherejs.com/netanelgilad/excel). After adding package with

```
meteor add netanelgilad:excel
```

and refresh I'm getting

```
global-imports.js?57a9dbc…:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Excel' of undefined
template.webapp.js?b8d1e7a…:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
webapp.js?42867d3…:27 Uncaught ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
login_buttons_dialogs.html:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
```

I'm not using this package anywhere in code yet, so I do not know why I'm getting e.g. 'Cannot read property 'Excel' of undefined'

**EDIT**

I've found a second library [here](https://atmospherejs.com/stef/import-export-excel). In this case page loads correctly. But when I want do do something in js like

```
var xlsxWriter = new SimpleExcel.Writer.XLSX();
```

I'm getting

```
webapp.js?a483464…:161 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Writer' of undefined
```

What could be the reason and how to fix it? How to correctly install one of these packages and get it to work?

Comment: Have you found the solution?